# Доступ к вложенным полям через рефлексию

Tags: golang, рефлексия, шаблоны

Я использую шаблоны, и стоит задача получить динамические данные, при этом не добавляя в родительскую структуру дополнительные поля.

К примеру, у меня инстанцируется конфиг 1 раз, и соответственно я могу написать функцию, которая будет брать оттуда данные, напрямую не добавляю структуру конфига Config к примеру в структуру PasswordReset.

Но, дочерних структур в конфиге у меня много, поэтому мне нужно напрямую вызывать что-то на подобие App.BaseURL

```
type Config struct {
  App App
}

type App struct {
  BaseURL string 
}

fsTemplate, err := template.New(name).Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "config": func(fieldName string) interface{} {
        f := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(cfg)).FieldByName(fieldName).Interface()
        return f
    },
}
```

Но так не сработает, я не смогу взять данные из вложенной структуры

```
{{define "content"}}
BaseURL: {{.config "App.BaseURL"}}
{{end}}
```

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: ничего не понял. 
приведите такой код, который можно воспроизвести. что такое name в template.New(name)? отвечать не нужно. просто приведите пример кода.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вы используете `Funcs`? Базовая нотация шаблонов вполне себе работает с многоуровневыми структурами: `BaseURL: {{.App.BaseURL}}`

Вот пример:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type Config struct {
    App App
}

type App struct {
    BaseURL string
}

func main() {
    cfg := Config{
        App: App{
            BaseURL: "http://example.com",
        },
    }
    fsTemplate, err := template.New("example").Parse(`
# Field inside field
BaseURL: {{.App.BaseURL}}`)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = fsTemplate.Execute(os.Stdout, cfg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
# Field inside field
BaseURL: http://example.com
```

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли, я хочу засунуть несколько структур в парсинг шаблонов, то есть что-то типа такого `fsTemplate.Execute(os.Stdout, firstStruct, secondStruct, cfg)` . Но сделать я этого не могу, соответственно мне нужна какая-то вспомогательная функция которая будет с другой структурі доставать те данные что мне нужны

Comment: То есть я делаю `fsTemplate.Execute(os.Stdout, passwordData)` , но при этом хочу подтянуть данные ещё из конфига (а это уже другая структура), но Execute() принимает только 1 interface{}. Возможно ли это сделать по другому?

Comment: @Manticore dot-нотация используется как для доступа к полям, так и для доступа к ключам map-ов. Объединяете ваши структуры в map `data := map[string]any{"FirstStruct": fs, "SecondStruct": ss, "Config": cfg}` и скармливаете шаблону `t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)`. Пример здесь: https://go.dev/play/